# WSO2 analytics confusion

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I would like to generate visualization(charts) on the usage of `API` accessed via WSO2 `API Manager`. I see many products and versions and cannot find right one. What is the difference between these products ?

> - API M Analytics 2.2
> - API DAS server 3.2
> - API Streaming processer 4.1

I'm using `API manager 2.2` version and need real time analytics so which one is suitable for this purpose and the corresponding documentation to setup ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With APIM 2.2.0 you should use APIM Analytics 2.2.0. It's a DAS with some custom code specific to APIM.

For statistics, APIM out of the box supports batch analytics only. However, it supports [alerts](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Configuring+Alerts).

You can read [this for analytics configurations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Configuring+APIM+Analytics).

Comment: Thanks I will try out.